How to modify the default type of element-plus？
For example, the type of el-button is '' | 'text' | 'default' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'info' | 'primary' | 'danger', how to append a type cancel
'' | 'text' | 'default' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'info' | 'primary' | 'danger' | 'cancel'
